# Python acuses Index out of range

Tags: python, indexing

I'm starting at Python and I was going pretty well until I get to classes part. Well, I'm trying to create a ChatBot, and in the main class the function Python `pensar()` returns `iniciar` so the function `resp()` can append it to self.recente list. It occurs as it has to be, but when the loop gets to `pensar()` again, it doesn't get the self.recente[-1]. Hope someone can help me.

**Here's the class code:**

```
class IA():
def __init__(self, nome):
    self.nome = nome
    self.recente = []

def ouvir(self):
    iniciar = input('»')
    iniciar = iniciar.upper()
    iniciar = iniciar.replace('O ', '')
    return iniciar
    
    
def pensar(self, iniciar):
    if iniciar == 'OI':
        return 'Ola, qual seu nome?'
    if self.recente[-1] == 'Olá, qual seu nome?':
        a = self.pegar_nome()
        b = self.resp_nome(b)
    
        
def pegar_nome(self):
    pass
    
    
def resp_nome(self, iniciar):
    pass
    

def resp(self, iniciar):
    self.recente.append(iniciar)
    print(iniciar)
```

**And here's the main.py one:**

```
    from Ia import IA

    tchau = ['TCHAU', 'XAU', 'ATE LOGO', 'ATÉ LOGO', 'ATE MAIS', 'ATÉ MAIS']
    
    while True:
        a = IA('Joao')
        b = a.ouvir()
        
        if b in tchau:
            print('Até mais')
            break
        
        c = a.pensar(b)
        a.resp(c)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of `IA` every iteration of the loop? That doesn't look right

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, post the traceback message so we see the details.

Comment: You need to call your function pensar inside the inisiar function.

Comment: `self.recente` starts off as an empty list. If `pensar` is called before `resp`, nothing has been added to the list. `self.recente[-1]` asks for the last value in the list but since its empty you get an index error. `pensar` must account for the case where there isn't anyting recent. So, what would like to happen in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is in these 2 statements:

1. `self.recente[-1]`    ---> trying to get an array element that does not exist.
2. `b = self.resp_nome(b)`   ---> referring to b before it is initialized.

**The problem can be fixed in these steps:**

1. Converting the statement into a condition that verifies the presence of specific value in the array.

   I.E., `if 'Olá, qual seu nome?' not in self.recente:`
2. Replace self.resp_nome(b) with self.resp_nome(a)

**Here is the working example with the 2 changes implemented:**

```
# File name: python-class-demo.py

class IA():
    def __init__(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome
        self.recente = []

    def ouvir(self):
        iniciar = input('»')
        iniciar = iniciar.upper()
        iniciar = iniciar.replace('O ', '')
        return iniciar
    
    
    def pensar(self, iniciar):
        if iniciar == 'OI':
            return 'Ola, qual seu nome?'
        if 'Olá, qual seu nome?' not in self.recente:
            a = self.pegar_nome()
            b = self.resp_nome(a)
    
        
    def pegar_nome(self):
        pass
    
    
    def resp_nome(self, iniciar):
        pass
    

    def resp(self, iniciar):
        self.recente.append(iniciar)
        print(iniciar)

tchau = ['TCHAU', 'XAU', 'ATE LOGO', 'ATÉ LOGO', 'ATE MAIS', 'ATÉ MAIS']

while True:
    a = IA('Joao')
    b = a.ouvir()
    
    if b in tchau:
        print('Até mais')
        break
    
    c = a.pensar(b)
    a.resp(c)
```

**Output:**

```
>python python-class-demo.py
»as
None
»OU
None
»TCHAU
Até mais
```

Answer (score -1):

You may write self variables in OOP:

```
>> (self.iniciar)
```

Without `self`, `iniciar` is a global variable

Comment: Polite correction: The variable is limited in scope to the parent class or function; certainly **not** global.

Comment: See [LEGB rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/2745495). Without `self`, `iniciar` will be scoped to the enclosing function or class.